# Convert file extension from .html to .php

Tags: c#, php, html

In development, should we convert the .html or .htm file extension to .PHP?
To implement the PHP session, and not to redirect if the session is destroyed?

I mean, in C# we use `RedirectToPagePermanent` to keep the user to only access the pages the system will be redirected.

How about PHP?

for example process.

1. Login Page
2. If the user exists:
3. Create a cache or session.
4. Redirect to Main Page.
5. if not then notify the user, and stays on the login page.
6. On Main Page, there is a logout button.
7. User clicks.
8. Session destroyed.
9. Redirect to the Login page.
10. if the user clicks the back button of chrome, the main page will not be shown or redirected because there is no session.

So, in PHP, should I convert all the .HTML or .Htm file to .PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert

**.html, .htm to .php to run as PHP and use the PHP session,**

Or you must tell your web-server to serve them as PHP

For example in Apache, Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

This will tell your web-server to treat html,htm files as PHP files.

Comment: So, this means invalid redirection will apply if i do this sir?

Comment: @Levesque Xylia you session coding for php will start working, you still need to check for the session and redirect it, as you do normally, only thing is you dont have to go and change the html extension of the files

Comment: So basically, we need to change the file extension of HTML?

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Php("yourpagename.php")